# Generic Repository, CreateObjectSet<T>() Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I was trying to implement a generic repository, and I have this right now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using Web_API.Models;

namespace Web_API.DAL
{
    class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext entities = null;
        IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

        public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext _entities)
        {
            entities = _entities;
            _objectSet = entities.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }

        ...
```

I'm having trouble with this method call:
                      `entities.CreateObjectSet<T>();`
It should be fine, however I get this error:

[image]

I have already added the System.Data.Entity to my project and at this point I don't know what else to do. I am following this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770156/Understanding-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change your method to look like this:

```
public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext _entities)
{
    entities = _entities;
    _objectSet = entities.Set<T>(); //This line changed.
}
```

This should have the function that you desire.
The `.Set<T>()` is the generic method that returns the `DbSet` of the type used.

UPDATE:

With the change in return type you will need to change your `_objectSet` type as well.

```
DbSet<T> _objectSet;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Has CreateObjectSet() been deprecated in the latest versions of EF?

Comment: `.CreateObjectSet()` is a method of `ObjectContext` which (to my knowledge) was replaced by `DbContext` in EF 4.1

Comment: If this answered your question please be sure to mark it as such.

Comment: I changed to entities.Set<T>() but it still gives me an error : [link](http://i.imgur.com/fGdcK0l.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.